# Bind an interface in java TCP connection

Tags: java, networking, tcp, network-programming

I have two interfaces in a solaris host. I would like to initiate two TCP connections to a single TCP server via both interfaces as shown in the diagram. Are there any options in Java to bind the interface to the TCP socket to override the local routing table?

I am attaching the network diagram,

[image: network_diagram]

I would like to use both the serial links bandwidth to get the data from server. Hence I would like to initiate the connection on both the interfaces.

thanks,

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't able to attach the network diagram here. My major problem is that I have two serial links connected to two routers. And the two routers are separately connected to my host. And I would like to initiate two different connections via two interfaces.

Comment: Upload it somewhere else and link it, without your diagram this is difficult to give a right answer.

Comment: Link to the picture - http://uploadpic.org/v.php?img=vSckl9f6Ze

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use

```
Socket s = new Socket(hostname, port, localInterface, 0);
```

However, many OSes do not honour this "hint" and will use the routing table anyway.

Comment: Ok, so, basically it is like the "register" keyword. Os is free to bind the socket with this interface or bind to the default interface. If it bind to different interface, then my application won't work. Are there any abstractions available in SocketChannel ?

Comment: I read something like "SO_BINDTODEVICE" in linux. But the socketchanneloptions class in java don't have "SO_BINDTODEVICE".

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_model Linux is typically weak hosted and will ignore which interface you bind a Socket to.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. How about solaris?

Comment: Thanks! Accept this. I will check if I can configure OS to respect the option and will let you know.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this:

```
Socket socket1 = new Socket();
socket1.bind(new InetSocketAddress("10.1.1.1", port));
socket1.connect(new InetSocketAddress("10.1.3.1", port));

Socket socket2 = new Socket();
socket2.bind(new InetSocketAddress("10.1.2.1", port));
socket2.connect(new InetSocketAddress("10.1.3.1", port);
```

Comment: No. The above code don't use the interface at all and always your socket1 and socket2 will bind to the default interface.

Comment: Sorry, the above is what I try to achive.. But the above will connect to the default interface which inturn will use the default routing table. Assuming  the default routing is via Router B, though I establish two socket connection to server, I will be going through the same link. So, instead if I say the socket to use the interface eth1, I can bypass the default routing and can use two separate links for two sockets.