# get IP from socket connect from localhost in java

Tags: java, sockets, ip, serversocket, inetaddress

how i get ip of socket conncet from localhost ?

**i try this :**

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1919);
        Socket test,s = new Socket("127.0.0.1",1919);

        test=ss.accept();
        System.out.println("we connect ");

        InetAddress IP=test.getInetAddress();
        System.out.println("IP of my system is := "+IP.getHostAddress()+"----"+IP);
```

the out put :

```
IP of my system is := 127.0.0.1----/127.0.0.1
```

**but i need :** IP:192.168.0.XXX

thanxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need : IP:192.168.0.XXX

You will never get it. It would be a wrong answer. Your Socket is connected via 127.0.0.1, so the source address can only be 127.0.0.1.

If you connected your a Socket to 193.168.0.XXX you would get that as the source address.

Comment: Take a look to: [Bind an interface in java TCP connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470459/bind-an-interface-in-java-tcp-connection), you can bind a socket with any active interface.