# Usage of multiple IP adress for sockets in JAVA

Tags: java, sockets

I recently bought an IP address so now I have two (and only one network card).
I want to test jsoup and launch an internet search (google for example) with each of the two addresses.

I read stuff on sockets and threads but I have not found any method of java.net class that allows me to specify the IP address to use when make of InetAdress (cause the InetAdress work with the one of the local machine ) .

**In other words , can we build a InetAdress with an extra IP?**

I'm really stuck, I tried everything.

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470459/bind-an-interface-in-java-tcp-connection? In other words, you can bind a socket to a specific IP address/interface.

Comment: thank you @vempo, it help, i will try it and come back again

Comment: thank you again @vempo but this solution is not suitable for me since i only have one network card

Comment: You can have multiple interfaces on a single network card. Maybe you need to start there.